# Как сделать так, чтобы в случае неверного ответа на вопрос " сколько будет 7*8?" заканчивалась программа?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");


    int a;
    cout << "Сколько будет 7*8?" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    switch (a)
    {
    case 56:
    {
        cout << "верно" << endl;
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        cout << "неверно, вы проиграли!" << endl;
        break;

    }

    }

    cout << "В каком году был основан Минск?" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1067:
    {
        cout << "молодец, знаешь" << endl;
    }
    default:
    {
        cout << "дебил(ка)" << endl;
        break;
    }
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: См. [man exit](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exit)

Answer (score 5):

```
cout << "неверно, вы проиграли!" << endl;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Много способов. Например можно вообше не написать программу, если ответ неверный:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    A() {
        cout << "Сколько будет 7*8?" << endl;
        cin >> a;            
    }
    ~A() { 
        if (a != 56)
           cout << "неверно, вы проиграли!" << endl;        
    }
};
int main() {      
    if (A().a == 56) { /*... некоторый код */  }
    //в обратном случаи ничего  не делаем     
    return 0;
}
```

Еще можно генерировать исключение, но не обработать, или просто возвращать из функции, как в другом ответе...